# How do I isolate an HTML5 audio player control function?

Tags: html, user-interface, user-controls, custom-controls, html5-audio

I want to isolate the 'play', 'pause', and 'stop' functions for my HTML5 player.  I want to put those in random places on my homepage (i.e., stop at the top left, play at the bottom-right, and pause at the middle of the page).  I also want to be able to isolate the tracker.  So, for example, have the tracker on the bottom-left of the page.

Can anyone tell me what it would take to isolate out one of the controls?  So, for example, "If the user clicks anywhere in div, "bottom-right", the audio will start to "play".  The tracker, bottom-left, will start to track, and the stop and pause buttons will go to ready state....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can affect the controls of a browser's native audio player, at least to the extent you want to, through CSS or JavaScript. Therefore, you'll need to omit the controls attribute from your audio tag (which will give you a player with no controls) and write the controls, and the logic behind the controls, yourself.

This [tutorial](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/) should give you enough to get started. However, you should note that, depending on the level of functionality you require, this may not be a trivial task.

You might also consider looking for a third-party library which supports the level of UI customisation you require. I haven't used it myself but have heard good things about [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/).

[Edit]

This [HTML5 audio test suite](http://areweplayingyet.org/) is quite handy as a summary of the API for the audio element and has links through to the appropriate entry in the W3 specification for each of the properties and events listed, though I would expect support to be inconsistent across the various browsers which support HTML5 audio.

I've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKUF6/) which demonstrates an HTML5 audio player controlled by a very basic set of custom controls (only tested in latest version of Chrome).

Comment: I'm not sure how much I agree with this answer.  I doubt that the logic needs to be rewritten.  I believe 'getting hold of the event triggers' is the only discovery that needs to be done.  I think it's possibly a jQuery event that starts HTML players going (something like `.($toggleplay)`).  I'm not sure how to sniff these out, though; thus, the question.  I may be able to update the player.

Comment: Perhaps my answer isn't clear enough, but I think we're generally in agreement here. I'm not suggesting you re-implement the whole player, but that you omit the browser's native controls from the player and implement your own controls in HTML. You can then use your custom UI to control the player instance using the JavaScript API which is exposed by the player (see the tutorial in my answer). I don't believe there are any native jQuery events or methods you can use to control a player but there are various jQuery based audio libraries which you may prefer to use as a starting point.

Comment: There must be some way to identify the event that's triggered when you press the play/stop button, though?

Comment: Also, it's a good answer.  Maybe I should just ask if someone knows how to identify that event.  That's really the final thing I'm looking for in an answer, though.

Comment: The Audio dom element fires a 'play' event when the player begins playback and a 'pause' event when the player is paused (see http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/media-elements.html#event-media-emptied). However, from your question, it seems to me that your fundamental problem is the separation of the browser's native player controls which I don't think you can do. See my updated answer for a jsfiddle which demonstrates the approach I think you'll need to take.

Comment: WOW!!!!  That's so cool.  What about changing the part of the song it's on, though?  You know, like clicking the tracker or rewinding?  Is it possible to push a time update request?  For example: "Click here to rewind," and it pushes the track time back by 5 seconds -or- "click the tracker to go to that place in the song", so you can click half way through and then be there?  I'm going to see if I can figure out how to do that.  Did you just read about this, or did you do something with a javascript inspector, like `ctrl-shift-j` in Chrome?

Comment: It's kind of sad that it doesn't work on my webserver, even though it works on the jsfiddle.

Comment: The example should work on your webserver. Have you definitely included jQuery (there's no import in the code because jsfiddle can do it automatically)? Have you checked the console for errors? Yes you should be able to make a full-featured tracker and a rewind button. The property you need to look at is currentTime which I think is both read and write.

Comment: I definitely did not include jQuery.  I didn't realize that they included that, automatically.  Thank you.  I'll try to figure out how to change times.  I think this is all very useful stuff to know.  I'm still learning JavaScript.